# How to not proguard Android/gradle dependencies

Tags: android, proguard

I want to know whether there is a better way for us to prevent proguard from obfuscating our dependencies.
Right now we basically keep all our dependencies manually (some if the statements might be redundant because it wasn't clean up properly).

This is a part of our proguard file which tries to keep everything necessary from our gradle dependencies:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep class org.altbeacon.** {
       *;
}

# support library
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

# Crittercism
-keep public class com.crittercism.**
-keepclassmembers public class com.crittercism.*
{
    *;
}

# keep logback-android logs
-keep class ch.qos.** { *; }
-keep class org.slf4j.** { *; }

# ZBar / QRCode-scanner
-keep class net.sourceforge.zbar.** { *; }
```

This are our gradle dependencies:

```
compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar')
compile files('app/libs/zbar.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final'
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.4.1'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.0'
```

Now I thought there might be some option to just tell proguard only to obfuscate the classes from my App. However I couldn't find anything.
I found `-libraryjars` but as far as I've read this is not the use for this.

The best I've come up with now is the following where `com.mycompany.myfirstapp` is my App's package:

```
-keep class !com.mycompany.myfirstapp.** { *; }
```

Is this the way to go or does anyone know a more conventient option?
I do not need to obfuscate or shrink my dependencies and I also do not want to have to specify each (and maybe forget one).

This is not only important for my App but our company is also providing and SDK so I want to give some guidelines to our customers, which seem to struggle with proguard sometimes.